# how to use Validator.pattern in angular 9

Tags: angular, angular-validation

```js
BGroup = new FormGroup({
  test: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern("[0-9]*$")])
});
```

Hi, I work with Angular 9
How can I set a pattern that takes only decimal numbers?
Like the numbers below.

```
11 OR 11.30 OR 9 OR 9.40 OR 11.05 OR 16 OR 11.80 ......
```

max number =20

min number=0

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
BGroup = new FormGroup({    
    test: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required,
                Validators.pattern('^\\d*\\.?\\d*$'), 
        Validators.min(0),
        Validators.max(20)])
});
```

Comment: Can you give an example? For which decimal number it can not match?

Comment: @Ali Please check https://regex101.com/r/HHYYUo/1/, it matches perfectly.

Comment: @huanfeng, @Ali, The RegExp is correct, However edit the answer to below `Validators.pattern('^\\d*\\.?\\d*$'),` You need to escape the `\\` character

Answer (score 1):

Below works

```js
constructor (private fb: FormBuilder) { }
pattern = '[0-9]+(\\.)?[0-9]*'
  BGroup = this.fb.group({    
    test: [null, [
      Validators.required, 
      Validators.pattern(this.pattern),
      Validators.min(0),
      Validators.max(20)
      ]
    ],
  });
```

I have created a [Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-1dw2v3)

Comment: I want to use a dot between decimals, for example (1.25) but the user can enter (1a25 or 1b25, etc.).
And I do not want that to be the case.

Comment: Just added `\\\` to escape the dot, Try now